# Create unique URL in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I need to create unique URL's for users. Currently I have the URL like this http://example.com/#/user/USER_NAME. But I need to modify this URL like http://example.com/#/USER_NAME. But I think this may create issues in the router. I anyone have a solution please help.

Comment: "But I think this may create issues in the router", Why? Or, what issues are you currently facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't get any problems if you use that approach. You just have to be carefull in how you define your route.

For instance:

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/:username', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/user.html',
        controller: 'UserController'
      }).
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      });
```

The home route will never get called in the above example, because `/:username` will match everything. So if you have multiple routes you just have to make sure the `/:username` route is the last route used.

```
$routeProvider.
          when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
          }).
          when('/:username', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/user.html',
            controller: 'UserController'
          });
```